# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable" on path: DexPathList

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-design-library, android-appcompat

I am getting the following error on `Intellij 15.0`

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable" on path: DexPathList
```

I have defined the Design & AppCompat libraries but i am not sure what's going wrong? The following is my Activity:

```
  import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

    public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);

    }
    }
```

My layout is:

I am not using gradle, i have also attached screen shots of my Project Structure[image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: show your gradle file

Comment: @Aashvi i am not using Gradle, i am using Intellij builder